# insert data from one database to other database dynamically

Tags: sql-server

I got one problem while insert data from one db to another

below is my code:

```
INSERT 
INTO myarchivedb.dbo.tblStoreOrderArchive
(
        [StoreOrderId]
       ,[CompanyId]
       ,[SiteId]
)
SELECT  StoreOrderId
    ,CompanyId
    ,SiteId
FROM mycurrentdb.dbo.tblStoreOrder
```

Above code is working fine but **myarchivedb** and **mycurrentdb**  will change periodically. how to do it dynamically using a variable.

Comment: As posted there is nowhere near enough information to provide a real answer here. Why do you think you can do this with a variable? Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: i want to do like this DECLARE @name nvarchar(512)='myarchivedb'
INSERT 
INTO [@name+.dbo.tblStoreOrderArchive]
(
   [StoreOrderId]
     ,[CompanyId]
     ,[SiteId]
)
SELECT StoreOrderId
  ,CompanyId
  ,SiteId
FROM mycurrentdb.dbo.tblStoreOrder

Comment: How can you not know the name of the database or table? You will have to use dynamic sql for this. Be very careful as this has a high risk of being vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Thank you... i will try for dynamic query

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
declare @db1 nvarchar(99) = 'myarchivedb.dbo.tblStoreOrderArchive';
declare @db2 nvarchar(99) = 'mycurrentdb.dbo.tblStoreOrder';

-- make sure your query and syntax is correct 
PRINT ('INSERT INTO ' +  @db1 + 
'([StoreOrderId] ,[CompanyId] ,[SiteId] ) SELECT StoreOrderId ,CompanyId ,SiteId FROM ' +  @db1)

EXEC ('INSERT INTO ' +  @db1 + 
'([StoreOrderId] ,[CompanyId] ,[SiteId] ) SELECT StoreOrderId ,CompanyId ,SiteId FROM ' +  @db1)
```

Comment: my procedure is very huge and i will lose indentation.. i want do this using a variable.concact the variable with tablename ..but it is not working

Comment: @user2841480 if we have to pass DB object dynamically then we have pass parameter dynamically and use dynamic query

Comment: can we do it using alias concept

Comment: @user2841480 no not we can't make a alias at insert to **DB.Schema.table** which works with select but still select we have to pass dynamically alias creating after actual object asiigned